# Migrating Infinispan 4.2 to 5.1 with the InternalEntryFactory class

Tags: java, jboss, infinispan

we are migrating from Infinispan 4.2 to 5.1 in our Java project.

In version 4.2, there's a class called InternalEntryFactory, which is located on the org.infinispan.container.entries package.

But in version 5.1, this class doesn't exists anymore. It was replaced by an interface called InternalEntryFactory on the org.infinispan.container package.

Here is my question: which implementation of this interface should I use now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which implementation to use depends on whether the cache is versioned or not. But you shouldn't instantiate the implementation classes directly, you should only use the interface:

```
  InternalEntryFactory internalEntryFactory = cache.getAdvancedCache().getComponentRegistry().getComponent(InternalEntryFactory.class);
```